# How do I turn off info logs in pocketsphinx-python

Tags: python-2.7, pocketsphinx

For example, running the `example.py` script of the [cmusphinx/pocketsphinx-python](https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx-python) package outputs a whole bunch of info to the terminal.  How do I switch it off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add

```
 config.set_string('-logfn', '/dev/null')
```