# Pocketsphinx Overflow Error

Tags: python, voice-recognition, pocketsphinx

I've been trying to use pocketsphinx for voice recognition but I keep getting an odd error. My code is as follows

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from os import environ, path
import pyaudio

from pocketsphinx.pocketsphinx import *
from sphinxbase.sphinxbase import *

MODELDIR = "pocketsphinx/model"
DATADIR = "pocketsphinx/test/data"

# Create a decoder with certain model
config = Decoder.default_config()
config.set_string('-hmm', path.join(MODELDIR, 'en-us/en-us'))
config.set_string('-lm', path.join(MODELDIR, 'MERLIN/MERLINv1.lm'))
config.set_string('-dict', path.join(MODELDIR, 'MERLIN/MERLINv1.dic'))
decoder = Decoder(config)


p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16, channels=1, rate=16000, input=True, frames_per_buffer=256)
stream.start_stream() 

in_speech_bf = False
decoder.start_utt()
try:
    while True:
        buf = stream.read(256)
        if buf:
            decoder.process_raw(buf, False, False)
            if decoder.get_in_speech() != in_speech_bf:
                in_speech_bf = decoder.get_in_speech()
                if not in_speech_bf:
                    decoder.end_utt()
                    print 'Result:', decoder.hyp().hypstr
                    decoder.start_utt()
        else:
            break
    decoder.end_utt()
except:
    print'Exception caught! Handeling...'
```

When I run the code, it is supposed to wait for me to speak, then print what it thinks I said and wait until I talk again.
In reality, it waits, prints, then throws an error and exits.

```
Result: DISPLAY CLOCK
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SR_test.py", line 26, in <module>
    buf = stream.read(256)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyaudio.py", line 608, in read
    return pa.read_stream(self._stream, num_frames, exception_on_overflow)
IOError: [Errno -9981] Input overflowed
```

I have looked this error up and the suggestion was to increase or decrease the chunk size. I have changed the chunks to 256-2048 to no avail. Does anyone know how to solve this? Thank you in advance.

By the way, since the code works up until the error, I also tried to trick it into ignoring the error with a try-except clause. Unfortunately, it just prints my statement and exits anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It fails to process audio in realtime most likely because your CPU is too slow, like you are trying to run on raspberry pi with large vocabulary.

You can see exact realtime numbers in pocketsphinx log output.

You need to get faster CPU or you can also try optimize the decoder configuration/vocabulary as described in [tutorial to decoder tuning](https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/decodertuning/)

Comment: As a matter of fact I am trying to run on a pi. Poketsphinx continuous works on my system though. I'll try to tune the decoder and see what happens

Comment: Whenever I try to modify the suggested parameters, I either end up with a segmentation fault or an unrecognized variable. I am adding them in the same manner as the dictionary, ie `config.set_string('-beam', '1e-50')`. Is this correct?

Comment: Also, although I am trying to run on a raspberry pi, my dictionary is only about 50 words. Is that considered large? Why does pocketsphinx_continuous work but my script overflows? Sorry for all the questions, I am a rather inexperienced programmer.

Comment: `config.set_float('-beam', 1e-50)` should work. 256 is pretty small buffer usually, pocketsphinx_continuous uses 4096. You also need to provide realtime numbers from the log to get further help.

Comment: I got it to work by stopping Pyaudio's stream and restarting it after each utterance. It seems to be running without issue now. One last question: Is there an option to turn off the log information in the terminal. I'd like to get it to just print what I tell the code to.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30734860/how-do-i-turn-off-info-logs-in-pocketsphinx-python